# Download a file using file ID in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, download, google-drive-api

I have a drive link to the CSV file that should be downloaded to my local machine. But not sure about how to do that. I can get the file name from the file ID. I am not clear on how to download the file.

```
function myFunction() {

  var fileID = '1e598PoBd76cALrawCR5mrKAaQdDiz2LR'
  var fileName = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getDownloadUrl()
  Logger.log(fileName);
}
```

Can anyone help me to download the file to the specified location on my local computer? TIA!

Comment: It depends. Would a Web App work for your case?

Comment: I need to set a trigger for a function that downloads the file based on the file IDs which will be populated in a column in google sheet

Comment: What kind of trigger is it? Also, would it be always need to be downloaded to the same computer? Or to the computer of whoever is dispatching the trigger (eg. somebody who edited the sheet)?

Comment: It should be downloaded in the same machine

Comment: For the same machine I'd consider to install Google Drive. This way any file saved on cloud Drive (in a synced folder) will appear on the local machine.

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. Do you need to avoid user interaction (make it fully-automated)? Can you have a local script? Can you run scripts and use Google libraries (for example using Python 3 with pip)?